# QuickDialog not showing dates in correct way

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, quickdialog

I am using quickdialog to consume dynamic forms. 
A webservice builds up a form with the quickdialog JSON. 
For a QDateTimeInlineElement he provides me this JSON.

```
    {"type":"QDateTimeInlineElement","title":"datum","placeholder":"vul in","bind":"textValue:datum","key":"datum","mode":"Date"},
   {"type":"QDateTimeInlineElement","title":"tijd","placeholder":"vul in","bind":"textValue:tijd","key":"tijd","mode":"Time"},
  {"type":"QDateTimeInlineElement","title":"datumtijd","placeholder":"vul in","bind":"textValue:datumtijd","key":"datumtijd","mode":"DateAndTime"},
```

In my code I put all the values in a dictionary using the following piece of code.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *script = [NSMutableDictionary new];
 [self.root fetchValueUsingBindingsIntoObject:script];
```

But when I look at an output of this dictionary I notice the following LOG

```
Date = "00:00:-34";
DateTime = "00:00:-34"; 
TIME = "00:00:-34";
```

Can anybody help me with this? Kind regards !